# FFMPEG how to control number of i-frames in encoded video?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

I want to re-encode a video using H264, and I want to control the number of i-frames contained in the re-encoded video. I've tried the following.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -y -c:v libx264 -crf 21 -sc_threshold 40 -c:a copy reencoded_video.mp4
```

This successfully re-encodes the video, but I can't affect the number of i-frames by adjusting the `-crf` and `-sc_threshold` values, as I have checked with `ffprobe`. Most of the time, the same set of i-frames are obtained regardless of the `-crf` and `-sc_threshold` values I set.

How do I control (to some extent) the number of i-frames in the re-encoded video? For example, how do I make every frame and i-frame? How do I re-encode it so that there is about 1 i-frame every 2 seconds?

## EDIT

It seems that I just wasn't trying a big enough range for `-sc_threshold`; setting it to 9999 solved the problem. I still can't find the documentation for a valid range of `-sc_threshold` though, could anyone point me to an official documentation that describes its valid range?

Comment: Some useful options may be found in this question: https://superuser.com/questions/908280/what-is-the-correct-way-to-fix-keyframes-in-ffmpeg-for-dash

Comment: If for whatever reason you require I-frame only encoding, use the `-intra` option for x264. The real question though, I guess, is: what actual problem are you trying to solve? Your question seems like an [xy-problem](http://xyproblem.info/).