# ffmpeg | How can I get the keyframes of a video sorted by time and position and save them to a text file?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, ffprobe

I'm new to this and I don't really understand a lot of things yet.
The following command tells me which line the video keyframe is on:

```
ffprobe -select_streams v -show_frames -show_entries frame=pict_type -of csv 720_000000.mp4 > IFrames1.txt
```

results:

```
...
[43] frame,B
[44] frame,P
[45] frame,B
[46] frame,B
[47] frame,B
[48] frame,P
[49] frame,B
[50] frame,B
[51] frame,P
[52] frame,I <-------
[53] frame,B
[54] frame,B
[55] frame,B
...
```

my example above only shows a result with the line where it is, but I would like to know in what second and minute it is, for example:

```
Iframes     Seconds
1           0
49          2
97          4
145         6
193         8
241         10
289         12
337         14
385         16
433         18
481         20
529         22
577         24
625         26
673         28
721         30
769         32
817         34
865         36
913         38
961         40
1009        42
1057        44
1105        46
1153        48
1201        50
1249        52
1297        54
1345        56
1393        58
```

maybe all this sounds very silly, I tried to replicate the command from one of the answers on this link, but I just get errors, and my level (account) is too low to respond and ask for details.

[iframes positions](https://superuser.com/questions/908280/what-is-the-correct-way-to-fix-keyframes-in-ffmpeg-for-dash)

I really appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Use

`ffprobe -select_streams v -show_entries frame=pict_type,pts_time -of csv=p=0 -skip_frame nokey -i INPUT` > Iframes.txt

Comment: thanks, but it generates repeated numerical data, like:
`1.066016,I`

`1.566016,I`

`2.066016,I`

`2.566016,I`

`3.066016,I`

`3.566016,I`

Comment: The first number is the time in seconds of each I-frame; the 2nd number is the frame type. If you want to display the records of all frames, remove `-skip_frame nokey`.